# Piping to Spidermonkey isn't working correctly

Tags: javascript, linux, spidermonkey

I've installed the latest version of Spidermonkey (JavaScript-C 1.8.5+ 2011-04-16) and have noticed a strange quirk that you might know the answer to.

In the past, if I did:

```
echo -n "print('hi');"
```

The result would come back as:

```
js> hi
```

However, now when I run that very same command, the return output I get is:

```
js> print('hi');
hi
js>
```

As you can see there are 3 lines of output, rather than just 1.

This normally wouldn't be an issue, but I'm working with a particular CMS which isn't handling this exception and so just errors out.

Is there a workaround? Should I just install an older version?

P.S. I understand Spidermonkey has the option of "e" (i.e. js -e "print('hi')") to run inline code, but once again the CMS I'm using doesn't work that way :\

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they have changed the way spidermonkey works in the newest versions. To overcome this issue in Ubuntu 10+ follow these instructions:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:launchpad/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install spidermonkey-bin
```

Now if you run:

```
echo -n "print('hi');" | js
```

It will print:

```
hi
```

Comment: This answer took me ages to find. The following resources helped:

http://www.cs.unc.edu/~gb/blog/2010/06/06/making-jslint-work-on-ubuntu-lucid/

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xulrunner-1.9.2/+bug/536950

Answer (score 1):

+1 for Anton Babushkin's answer, but the newest SpiderMonkey command line option parser actually a subtle distinction here:

```
$ echo -n "print('hi');" | ./js
js> print('hi');
hi
js> 
$ echo -n "print('hi');" | ./js -
hi
```

I rewrote the option parser only a few months ago so this would have to be with an up to date version.